# Nuxt-Auth (Google Provider): JWT received from strapi backend but No redirection to home page

Tags: nuxt.js, strapi, nuxt-auth

I'm building a frontend app based on NuxtJS with Strapi as the backend. I've already configured the google provider on Strapi. However, once it's time to connect it with the frontend I run into a problem.
Basically, after logging in, it redirects me to the frontend URL with the token and not directly to the homepage.

Below is my nuxt-config code:

```js
auth: {
  strategies:{
    google: {
      clientId: 'google_client_id',
      codeChallengeMethod:'',
      endpoints: {
        authorization: 'https://strapi.backend.com/connect/google',
        token: 'https://strapi.backend.com/token',
        userInfo: 'https://strapi.backend.com/users/me'
      },
      token: {
        property: 'id_token',
        type: 'jwt',
        maxAge: 1800
      },
      responseType: 'token',
      grantType: 'authorization_code',
    }
  }
}
```

Login.vue code

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    async google(){
    await this.$auth.loginWith('google')
  }
}
```

Let me know please if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried using the `redirect` key?

```js
auth: {
  redirect: {
    home: '/',
  },
  ...
}
```